# How Do I Update My Model from a checkbox? Rails 7.0.4 + Stimulus.js

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs

I was using Rails 7.0.4 to make a to-do list application, but I'm trying to update my model of a checkbox using stimulus.js. For that:

**index.html.erb**

```
        <tbody>
          <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
            <tr data-controller="task" 
                data-task-update-url="<%= task_path(task) %>">
              <td><%= task.task_title%></td>
              <td><%= task.task_date%></td>
              <td>
                <input type = "checkbox"
                    data-action = "task#toggle"
                    data-target = "task.completed"
                    <% if task.completed %> checked <% end %>>
              </td>
              <td>
                <%= link_to edit_task_path(task) do %>
                  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                <% end %>
              </td>
              <td>
                <%= link_to task_path(task), data: { "turbo_method": :delete, turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
                  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                <% end %>
              </td>  
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
```

**task_controller.js**

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {

    static targets = [ "completed" ]

    toggle (event) {
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("task[completed]", this.completedTarget.checked);

        fetch (this.data.get("update-url"), {
            body: formData,
            method: 'PATCH',
            credentials: "include",
            dataType: "script",
            headers: {
                    "X-CSRF-Token": getMetaValue("csrf-token")
             },
        }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.status != 204) {
                event.target.checked = !event.target.checked 
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note, you should use stimulus values instead of the `data-task-update-url` to make it more stimulus compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Task` model has a `task_complete` method, but you are asking for `complete` in your code.

Look at the error message. It says `Undefined method 'complete'` that's because nowhere in your code you have `def`ined it.

You could ask another method `complete?`

```rb
def complete?
  task_complete
end
```

and add that into your erb code.